# Cpselect for 2 images in Matlab and saving the image with plots

Tags: image, matlab

I am selecting corresponding points in 2 images using the `cpselect` function in matlab. So, at the end, I get 2 arrays, one for the points of the input image, and other for the points of the base image. My question is whether I can save these points on the image subsequently, and save the following images, so both the images show the points marked on them. Also, I need to mark the points in different colors. Any ideas would be appreciated! My current code is as follows:

```
>> I1 = imread('C:\Users\5460\Desktop\Computer Vision\qn4\inria1.tif');
>> I2 = imread('C:\Users\5460\Desktop\Computer Vision\qn4\inria2.tif');
>> imshow(I1);
>> imshow(I2);
>> cpselect(I1,I2)
```

I have realised one method, but this is only adding points one by one. As follows(x,y) is (70,22):

```
>> imshow(I1);
>> hold on;
>> plot(70,22,'b*');
```

Is there any way to plot multiple points in different colours in one go? 
Also, how to save the images with pots as jpeg? Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

if your points are stored inside vectors `x` and `y`:

```
hold all
for n = 1:numel(x)
    plot(x(n),y(n),'*')
end
hold off
```

this will give seven unique colours (then they will repeat if you have more than seven data points).  You can see the default MATLAB colours with this command:

```
get(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder')
```

read this for more:

http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/creating_plots/defining-the-color-of-lines-for-plotting.html

Comment: Thanks! Does it give color in a particular order? or is it random?

Comment: The link in my answer explains the order of the colours, and how to set your own.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks! Is there any way to save the images? or do we have to plot and save separately? Thanks so much :)